# Convert Business conditions to Boolean expressions

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

In my enterprise application I have business rules like :

1. `((AMOUNT < 20000.00) || ((AMOUNT >= 20000.00) && (RISKIND == 'N')))`
2. `(ind = A1 || ind = A2 || ind = A3 || ind = S1 || ind = S2 || ind = S9)`

Now expression #1 can be converted to a boolean expression like:
(X || (!X && Y))

But I am not sure how the second expression be denoted in boolean form:

can it be like below ? :
`(A || B || C || D || E || F)`. I want to keep the number of variables as less as possible for me feed it to a boolean solver and get results quicker

Comment: Are you interested in checking the satisfiability of your constraints?  Are the values of "ind" all mutually exclusive?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi yes I would like check the satisfiability as well. But before that need to understand how the real world business condition can be represented in the form I mentioned. And yes `ind` has mutually exclusive values.

Comment: In all likelihood, you want an SMT solver, rather than a Boolean satisfiability solver.  Satisfiability Modulo Theories is a fancy name, and those tools are very sophisticated, but in a nutshell, they allow you to detect that $x < 10 \wedge x > 15$ cannot be satisfied.  At the propositional level, $p \wedge q$ doesn't express the same condition.

Comment: As a last step I will be checking the satisfiability of the expression preferably using a Java library (there are lots of open source libraries available)

Comment: Some SMT solvers have Java bindings.  Z3 and CVC4 offer Java APIs and both are the real deal.  You know your application and I don't, and it well may be that integrating a heavy piece of machinery like a full-fledged SMT solver is not viable, but I'll reiterate that propositional logic is the wrong tool for the talk you describe.  Both Z3 and CVC4 have web-based interfaces that allow you to familiarize with them.

Comment: Thanks that I am new to these concepts. How can I apply the SMT strategy for my rule `(ind = A1 || ind = A2 || ind = A3 || ind = S1 || ind = S2 || ind = S9)` or any such business rule ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMT solvers allow one to reason with logical combinations of arithmetic statements.  Z3 has the most flexible web-based interface, with a few extensions on the standard SMT-LIB 2 format that make the task of modeling your query easier.  So, I'll show what one can enter [here](http://rise4fun.com/z3/%22here%22) to model and reason about yor query.

```
;; Trace subset of unsatisfiable constraints
(set-option :produce-unsat-cores true)

;; Declare enumerated types.
(declare-datatypes () ((Risk None Low Medium High)))
(declare-datatypes () ((Index A1 A2 A3 S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9)))

;; Declare the constant symbols of our model.
(declare-const amount Real)
(declare-const risklevel Risk)
(declare-const ind Index)

;; Assert constraints on the model.  Named constraints can be traced.
(assert (! (or (< amount 20000) (and (<= 20000 amount) (= risklevel None))) 
           :named norisk))
(assert (! (or
               (= ind A1) (= ind A2) (= ind A3)
               (= ind S1) (= ind S2) (= ind S9)) :named rightindex))

;; Sanity check: Are the constraints satisfiable?
(check-sat) ; expect 'sat'
;; See if we can simplify one of the constraints. (Not much.)
(simplify (or (< amount 20000) (and (<= 20000 amount) (= risklevel None))))
;; Get values of amount, risklevel, and ind that witness satisfiability.
(get-value (amount risklevel ind))

;; Start new context.
(push)
;; Do these choices satisfy the constraints?
(assert (! (and (= amount 100000) (= risklevel Medium)) :named example))
(check-sat) ; expect 'unsat'
;; Get explanation.
(get-unsat-core)
(pop)
;; We can now check another example or simply say, 'That's all, folks!'
(exit)
```

Running Z3 on this input produces:

```
sat
(or (not (<= 20000.0 amount)) (and (<= 20000.0 amount) (= risklevel None)))
((amount 20000.0) (risklevel None) (ind A1))
unsat
(norisk example)
```

The last line says that the unsatisfiability of the constraints depends on a conflict between the `norisk` and `example` constraints.  The `rightindex` constraint has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But on my part it would be a steep learning curve. Also I would like to implement a lightweight SMT solver. any pointers ?

Comment: If you only need to deal with conjunctions (AND) of simple arithmetic constraints, you may be able to make do with a solver for "difference logic," which in its simplest form amounts to the Bellman-Ford algorithm for shortest paths.  A very accessible exposition is in Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein.  (Look for "difference constraints and shortest paths.")  You could then deal with disjunctions (OR) by enumeration of the possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Would the expressions in my question fall under "First order logic" or am I stating it wrong ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.